# Decomposing a matrix into a product of two matrices and making the right-hand one irreversable

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

Let *X* be any *n $\times$ m* matrix.

I want to decompose it like *X=AB* where *A* is *n $\times$ p* and *B* is *p $\times$ m* with *p* which is larger than both *n* and *m*.

I wondered

1. Can we always decompose any *X* into *A* and *B* while we can set *p* freely.
2. Is *A* inferable with *X* and *B*?

In my knowledge, *B* doesn't have right-hand pseudo inverse so inferring the original *A* from X and B is not possible. (no *B'* exists for *$A=XB'$*).

Answer (score 1):

1. Sure, you can always let $A = [X, 0_{n \times (p-n)}]$ and $B = [I_m, 0_{m \times (p-m)}]^T $, then $X = AB$ for any $p$ larger than $n$ and $m$. I guess you're not looking for such trivial solutions but then you need to tell us what $A$ or $B$ should look like.
2. Not uniquely. For a given factorization $X = AB$ you can find another one $X = \bar{A} \bar{B}$ via $\bar{A} = A T$ and $\bar{B} = T^{-1} B$ for any invertible square $p$. Even if you know $B$, this does not give away $A$ since $B$ has a non-empty left null space, i.e. $y^T B = 0$ has non-trivial solutions in $y$ and hence we have $(A + A_0) + B = AB + A_0 B = X$ for any $A_0$ in the left null space of $X$. You can find *one* possible solution via the pseudo inverse $A_p = X \cdot B^+$, but it's not unique.

Comment: Thank you!
I want A and B be composed of random real numbers so I can hide A from outsiders who know B and X.